# 8 errors repeating that "ProjectName.Tests.dll cannot be found"

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've tried rebuilding, closing and opening, unloading and reloading the project... I can't seem to make it go away. The fact that the exact same error is repeated 8 times makes no sense either. `ProjectName.Tests.dll` compiles just fine, and I can make all tests pass.

This is the error:

> Error while reading '...\obj\Debug\ProjectName.Tests.dll': Could not find a part of the path '...\obj\Debug\ProjectName.Tests.dll'

And this is the print-screen of Visual Studio:

[image]

Comment: I prefer to look at the `Output` pane, and search for the first occurrence of an error. That often makes more sense. - Also look in the Project Properties for the target framework version, CPU type etc; then for references with different versions.

Comment: @BernhardHiller The `Output` panel doesn't show anything related to the error. I've checked the Project Properties of the Test project and they seem to match with the core project. It is worth reminding that everything works just fine, the only problem is that it is annoying to have 8 errors masking other potential compilation errors while coding.